# React Native Image Not Loading. What am I doing wrong ? The Image will not load if i pass a uri to it

Tags: reactjs, image, react-native

I am trying to load an image in a screen on react-native.
The image uri is passed to the screen via props.

For some reason the image is not loading and I don't know why i've checked multiple resources and changed the image to a local image saved down in the assets folder.

When i try to load the image dynamically it will not load and displays a blank image. The text is displayed correctly. However hardcoded image uri loads fine.
Please advise.

```
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, Text, Image, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';

const App = ({imageUri, imageText}) => {
    console.log (`Image uri: ${imageUri}`)
    console.log(`Image Text : ${imageText}`)
  
  // const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    // console.log (`Loading : ${loading}`)
    // const imgUri = {uri:'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png'}
    
    return (
        // <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View style={styles.containerMain}>   
                {/* 
                <Image source={{uri: imageUri}}
                // style={styles.pic}>
                </Image>} */} // Image does not load not sure why !!! 

                <Image source={require('../assets/images/logo-og.png')}
                style={styles.pic}/>
                <View style={styles.bottomView}>
                    <Text style={styles.textStyle}>{imageText}</Text>
                </View>

            </View>
        // </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    activityIndicator: {
        position: 'absolute',
       // color: Colors.primary,
        alignSelf: 'center',
    },
    containerMain: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
    bottomView: {
        width: '100%',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.6)',
        position: 'absolute', 
        bottom: 50, 
    },
    textStyle: {
        flex: 1,
        color: '#fff',
        fontSize: 30,
        fontFamily: 'pacifico-regular',
        flexShrink: 1,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    pic: {
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
});
export default App;
```

Any Idea what is causing the Image to not load ?

Comment: In which android OS you are running the app ?

Comment: I'm running on IOS

Comment: Have you tried opening the image URL in any browser?

Comment: Yes @Jigneshmayani that works fine and the images exist. I tried changing it to pick a local image from a local folder and that still gives a blank image.

Comment: @AshleyVaz Check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

As per the code observation, it will not work to pass the object in the Uri key of the Image component source prop.

For Ex:

if you are supposed to pass the uri as below:

```
const imgUri = {uri:'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png'}
```

you only have to pass the imgUri variable to the source props as below

```
source={imgUri}
```

instead of

```
source={{ uri: imgUri }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the link to **imgUri** const as a string

```js
const imgUri = 'https://reactjs.org/logo-og.png'
```

and keep the source as it is but keep in mind to add the resizeMode as a prop for the Image component

```js
<Image source={{uri: imageUri}}
       resizeMode='contain' //new line added
/>
```

also using require() should works, try to add the resizeMode to the Image Component:

```js
<Image source={require('../assets/images/logo-og.png')}
       style={styles.pic}
       resizeMode='contain' />
```

hope this will help you